# scroll to a component on a click using Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, scroll, scrollto

Hey i'm trying to create a simple navigation bar with a few link buttons. i want that when i click on a button, it will scroll to the right component. i know i can do it with jquery using ScrollTo() but with Angular i don't have all the HTML in 1 page. is it possible to make it work with angular ?

this fiddle describes the outcome i'm looking for :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="relativeanchor"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/francescov/4DcNH/

Comment: How do you want to scroll to an element which is not in the HTML? Or you mean one HTML file? Are the component's in the DOM?

Comment: well i think ill have to use @Output() and @Input() decorators in order for this to work... your question made me realize that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash`. like this.

```
<button (click)="goTo('myComponent')"></button>
```

This is the `goTo` function in your component:

```
goTo(location: string): void {
    window.location.hash = location;
}
```

Then this is the component you want to navigate to:

```
<my-component id='myComponent'></my-component>
```

When you click the button, it will navigate to the element with an id "myComponent" which is your component.

Comment: it does work . do i have any way to add animation to it ?